# php array matching between two arrays

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

```
$a = array('one'=> val, 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten'); 
$b = array('four'=> val, 'one'=> val, 'eight'=> val, 'five'=> val)
```

I have two arrays as shown above.

need result like this:

will output:

```
'one' => val
'two' => 0
'three' => 0
'four' => val
'five' => val
'six' => 0
'seven' => 0
'eight' => val
'nine' => 0
'ten'  => 0
```

Is there easy way to do this?

any help would be good

Comment: Is 'height' a typo, or deliberate? And what's this got to do with MySQL?

Comment: sorry its typo, let me correct it

Comment: Your `$a`-array looks like `'one'=>val, [0]=>two, [1]=>three..etc`, you wish to compare slightly different array structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually array_intersect does something like this. It creates an new array out of these 2 arrays, only holding the values which are available in both arrays.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php

> `array_intersect()` returns an array containing all the values of
>   array1 that are present in all the arguments. Note that keys are
>   preserved.

edit: You should rather use array-diff,

> Compares array1 against one or more other arrays and returns the
>   values in array1 that are not present in any of the other arrays.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

The code for your output described above would be something like:

```
<?php
$a = array('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten'); 
$b = array('four', 'one', 'eight', 'five');

//Find matches and not matches
$matches = array_intersect($a, $b);
$dontmatches = array_unique(array_merge($a, $b));

//Set all dont matches to 0
for($i = 0; $i<count($dontmatches);$i++)
    $dontmatches[$i] = 0;

$final = array_merge($matches, $dontmatches);
print_r($final);
?>
```

I used both described functions from above plus the following:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: yes, I am familiar with it but it gives only that data exist.

i need all data and show them as 0

Comment: @user4499992 See my edit, mind that I had to change your array  structure, as it represented  2 different structures.